# pandas, chained indexing, spaces in csv, and speed

Tags: python-2.7, indexing, pandas

My question is regarding speed of indexing using the Pandas module in Python 2.7.9.  I am using Pandas 0.12.0 because all versions above 0.12.0 make chained indexing slow with the dataframe I am using with missing column values (even with chained indexing warnings off).  Here is the link to my [csv](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~ericxu/TESTDF.csv) ('TESTDF.csv')

python input:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

#importing raw data
Rawdf = pd.read_csv('TESTDF.csv')

# chained 1
t = time.time()
Rawdf['MONTH']=None
for i in range(0,1000):
    Rawdf['MONTH'][i] = int(Rawdf['DATE'][i][0:2].replace('/',''))
elapsed = time.time() - t  
print elapsed  

# unchained 1
t = time.time()
Rawdf['MONTH'] = None
for i in range(0,1000):
    Rawdf.loc[i,'MONTH'] = int(Rawdf.loc[i,'DATE'][0:2].replace('/',''))
elapsed = time.time() - t  
print elapsed

# unchained 2
t = time.time()
Rawdf['MONTH'] = None
#ADD MONTH, DAY, YEAR, and HOUR columns
for i in range(0,1000):
    Rawdf.loc[i,'MONTH'] = int(Rawdf.loc[i,'DATE'][0:2].replace('/',''))
elapsed = time.time() - t  
print elapsed  

# chained 2
t = time.time()
Rawdf['MONTH']=None
#ADD MONTH, DAY, YEAR, and HOUR columns
for i in range(0,1000):
    Rawdf['MONTH'][i] = int(Rawdf['DATE'][i][0:2].replace('/',''))
elapsed = time.time() - t  
print elapsed
```

Here is my python output:

```
0.0684299468994
9.38544201851
8.49306797981
0.0324759483337
```

As you can see, chained is much faster.  Why is there such a speed difference? I'm pretty sure it has something to do with missing column values in the csv, which is interesting to imagine that it could make that much of a difference.

Comment: I can't run your code, also what happens if you flip the order so chained indexing first and then the correct one last? Normally timing operations have to computed several times and an average taken of the fastest times to factor out any caching

Comment: Please edit code updates into your question as the formatting is lost in comments, I just ran that code and got `chained indexing processing time:  2.3311331272125244
non-chained indexing processing time:  2.579148054122925` I then flipped the order and got: `non-chained indexing processing time:  2.503142833709717
chained indexing processing time:  4.8432769775390625` so I don't see as big a difference as you and the order matters

Comment: Edit your question and add the complete code and delete your comment

Comment: @EdChum is probably using version 15 or 16, and it's quite likely ```loc``` has improved in performance since version 12.  You could check the release notes if you are interested.  My results (with version 15.2) are certainly much closer to Ed's than to yours.

Comment: thanks guys. i've modified my question.

Comment: It feels like there's an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here -- instead of trying to figure out how an outdated version of pandas behaves, it would probably be more productive to describe your actual problem ("here's what I have, here's what I want, here's what I've done so far, but it's too slow-- is there a better way?").  For example, if all you want to do is extract the month, day, year, and hour into columns, I'll bet several hundred quatloos we can beat your best time in *modern* pandas.

Comment: @DSM -- Yes, of course.  I get exact opposite results as Eric.  Added to my answer below for readability, but loc in 15.2 is 25x faster than chained.  Eric -- Time to upgrade!!!

Comment: @ DSM yeah I really don't want to use the old pandas but something fishy is going on and it's not a small speed difference...it's a BIG one  .  @ JohnE I got the opposite of yours

Answer (score 0):

(results from pandas v15.2, using Eric's code above exactly (except using `nrows=1000` with `read_csv()` since the rest of the code only uses first 1,000 rows.  If that matters then I think the code should be altered to use more than first 1,000 rows as it's a bit of a pain to read in a big csv for no real reason.  Also, you could recreate the csv with a date_range essentially).

```
25.5060670376   # chained 1
1.0301091671    # unchained 1
1.3660838604    # unchained 2
26.4075160027   # chainedd 2
```

(note:  code below here is based on a prior version of the question since edited away, but I believe the points are still valid so I'll just leave it here)

To expand on the good points that @EdChum is making...  It's much easier to do this in ipython, and the difference between the 2 methods is much closer (and you don't have to worry about the ordering this way):

```
In [11]: pd.__version__
Out[11]: '0.15.2'

%timeit for i in range(0,6000,3): df.loc[i,'test']=666
1 loops, best of 3: 578 ms per loop

%timeit for i in range(0,6000,3): df['test'][i]=666
1 loops, best of 3: 220 ms per loop
```

I'm not bothering to reset 'test' to None but that's really not important for the timing (as you just repeatedly overwrite anyway).  And also, I don't know what you are ultimately attempting to measure, but if you vectorize the above code (which you would want to do in an actual application), the two methods are basically the same speed (not to mention around 1000x faster than the non-vectorized versions):

```
%timeit df.ix[0:6000:3,'test']=666
1000 loops, best of 3: 348 µs per loop

%timeit df['test'][0:6000:3]=666
1000 loops, best of 3: 352 µs per loop
```

Btw, there have been lots of performance improvements since 12.0, it's really tough to believe you are best off being 4 versions behind.  If you are finding some situation where you need chained indexing for speed, you might want to post that specific example here rather than this example test.  I think it's very likely someone here will have a method that is as fast as whatever you are doing with chained indexing.

Comment: I just did it with pandas v 15.2  (and nrows=1000) and my chained is still faster :

    0.117352962494  chained
    1.13028311729   unchained
    0.828242063522   unchained
    0.102880001068   chained

Comment: @Eric  -- I have no idea what's going on then.  I just copied and pasted your code exactly (again, except for the nrows=1000)

Comment: very weird i keep getting the opposite of you....your nrows suggestion helped the speed in general quite a bit and I truly appreciate all your help.

Comment: @Eric -- clearly one of us is crazy, we'll have to get a third opinion from Ed or DSM to figure out which of us it is.  ;-)

Comment: @ JohnE it's all good lol.  I just downgraded back and got faster for chained and slower for unchained =P ...